# Password problems. Found Wrong password on auto fill email doesnt exist

Tags: passwords

When I go to marlboro.com on Google Chrome and I click on where I sign in my autofill comes up and I have three different ones one of them is my actual Gmail and the other one says the first two letters of my actual Gmail and then XXX behind it and I don't know why it says that or what has that on there my boyfriend thinks that I have another Gmail and I need to prove to him that I do not. How do I do that. I've tried looking in my Gmail account settings, chrome settings I've googled it